# Is there a way to create multiple sitemap.xml files using XMLSitemap module, using arbitrary node properties?

Tags: xml-sitemap

I am using XMLSitemap module for version 7
https://www.drupal.org/project/xmlsitemap

Out of the box, it lets me create just one sitemap.xml file. With internationalization turned on, it can generate one sitemap.xml file per language.

Is there a way (maybe using hooks?) to generate multiple xml files, based on an arbitrary node field value? For example, product categories - one sitemap.xml file per category